# Azure devops cicd gitlab integration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, gitlab, pipeline, azure-aks

I am using an external private gitlab repository for code and using `azure-devops` for cicd pipeline. When the user checks in code to the gitlab project repository `azure-devops` builds and releases. It names the build as CI BUILD. How can I get username and current changeset (name of the user who just checked in his code and his changeset files name) to show with build in `azure-devops`?

Comment: Share more details about how you want the information to be shown with your build

Comment: not working for external gitlab repository

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the build record of the CI trigger in the build pipeline.
The username of the changer and commit will be displayed at the top of the record. Click commit and you will be taken to the changed file.

In the sample ,I use the github repository for code ,I think the same is true with gitlab.

[image]